# Who is Nancy Bonds?

Tags: civilization-6

In Civ VI when you discover [Mount Kilimanjaro](http://civ6.gamepedia.com/Mount_Kilimanjaro) you get the following quote:

> "As it turns out, Mount Kilimanjaro is not wi-fi enabled, so I had to
>   spend two weeks in Tanzania talking to the people on my trip."
>
> -Nancy Bonds

I've never heard of a Nancy Bonds and Google searches don't show anything useful, but generally speaking they only use quotes from famous people in Civ. So who is she?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Thanks to Ramhound for this answer*

Nancy Bonds is a graduate of the University of Texas at Austin who went on a trip to Kilimanjaro and [wrote a blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20131113150016/http://blogs.mccombs.utexas.edu/bba-news/2013/08/05/the-five-things-i-learned-climbing-kilimanjaro/) about it. That blog contains the quote (emphasis mine):

> **As it turns out, Mount Kilimanjaro is not wi-fi enabled, so I had to**
> **spend two weeks in Tanzania** (with a couple exceptions) **talking to the**
> **people on my trip.** Initially wary of the lack of phone usage, I soon
> adapted to some old school communication methods, from writing letters
> to chatting in front of fires. We told stories from elementary school,
> awkward tales from middle school, absurd high school drama, and
> incredible adventures. We all have stories. Whether they come from
> family trips to Brazil or the time you tried to jump over a wall and
> missed. I think most of the time we just forget to tell them to each
> other . We forget that we make stories every day. After hearing about
> my friend pulling a row boat to shore in a hippo pool, after listening
> to my guide talk about his first trip up the mountain, and after
> rattling off my own tale about a fall down a switchback, I realized we
> all have something to say. We all have moments that we can share with
> each other. Be adventurous, take a step back, and remember to tell
> your story.

Comment: I always tell my story, every chance I get. Sometimes it surprises people that I'm so eager to talk about it, but if I don't share it, who will?